plot_surface produces no accurate 3d plot
I am following the 3D surface (colormap) from Matplotlib tutorial in order to plot $f(x,y)=(y-x)^2+x^{5}$.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

# Make data.
X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
Y = np.copy(X)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.power(Y - X, 2) + np.power(X, 5)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1000.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
# A StrMethodFormatter is used automatically
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter("{x:.02f}")

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.savefig("plot.pdf")

I am not sure if the issue arises because there are better plot functions to achieve this or generating few points (for 1000 sample points takes long time) or bad range.

After removing, ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1000.01), is the result what you expect?

Improved a lot https://i.imgur.com/mZS09uA.png Thank you.
